# How to dynamically format X-Axis and Y-Axis labels in Echarts?

Tags: echarts

I know I can set the width and then use ellipsis but for all the charts I dont want to use same width for labels. Some charts will have more labels and some will have less. For some charts, I want to show alternate labels and for some charts I want to show all labels but truncated value and on hover I want to show the full value. I tried going through all the options in doc but couldn't find any option to add on hover texts on label and also how to dynamically show formatted labels.
I have 4 needs

1. How to show tooltip on hover of label
2. How to dynamically truncate label name depending on the space
3. How to dynamically show alternate labels if the number of labels are high
4. How to dynamically rotate label if the space is not there for those labels

I can think of one solution if i can get the width of `X-Axis.axisline` then I can divide the width bu number of labels and if the resultant number is small I can adjust all the three dynamic cases. But, I am not able to get the width of `axisline`.

Thanks, maybe this question can help a lit of people.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBEZjABtIRsAuZdLKnMAJwgHMGBTWsnAQwA8IBnbADSVqmbNz4AFYBGhhW7VBhHVsBDgCNmBBcOXLsvABbAA7uzoBXZkKV6R2AGYwwvCAC9m7AIwAmXXYBffyog21gAmypsLgBBHn5yAG1grEU7LFwATxBPcmwAYw45BmBaTMEU-2gOAFtcnC5YcX5I9M54gBkNLR0wtpxDCAATZgB5ADdWNRJyS2tK6giFqKGijnZkvrbo5thVsA5YLwqt9J34vbXYHxP-qK5d_cOAZlu70QeLp9gAFjf3858S4HWAAVn-d0BvGBhwAbBD-lCYbAAOwI7afIHfAAc6LOmOh3wAnHi7Ejvl4AAykvTkq5eY6tAEE5G-Gn6FkU15MyGc-l_ZZYAC6C1CVCFPOwmTifF6tLA2Xq2HGHAIVghSzCBlYEGYCVgmz0aW21Tq7G19D1R3ZogVOXN6g4bB5tKeG0FIl8PlBPxdbWeoNhfvSXmxlODdhR4Y91C8Eb0QZjVB88eUYdTnthlOecaTWFD0dOdi8Px-PmeGeosOeZcrVCJsJTecwXiJ2MTRb0fk7wtFEeNZ1NSt4OqtN0rWXteUdzpj2DdSWbRx83t9S4DHfeLfTS8LW6Odawe63TZ7ImP7y8WZzh-3F7uJbLFaX1drS4bp_39_63f6IqLYq9mgARAA)

Comment: You can get the width of the axis in the chart object itself. It seems to be under `chart._chartsViews[0]._coordSys._axes.x._extent`

Comment: @MatthiasMertens Calculating width and then taking decision will be the correct approach? Or is there any other way we can achieve?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Some example code would be helpful.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens I have added an example. If you can see there is a long label at starting. I want to truncate it and i can do that with formatter. But, I don't want to hardcode the label length to 10 characters. I want to dynamically decide depending on labels length and chart area 
1. how many labels to show
2. should i rotate the labels to 30 degree
3. should i truncate just 5 characters and i have enough space
4. if i truncate the label then how can i show the tooltip on hover of label

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to calculate width dynamically. If you want to truncate the axis label, you must have to provide a specific width.

However, a good approach is to display the axis label when hovering over the chart.

Here is my basic implementation for showing the axis label on chart hover.

[EXAMPLE:](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBEZjABtIRsAuZdLKnMAJwgHMGBTWsnAQwA8IBnbADSVqmbNz4AFYBGhhW7VBhHVsBDgCNmBBcOXLsvABbAA7uzoBXZkKV6R2AGYwwvCAC9m7AIwAmXXYBffyog21gAmypsLgBBHn5yAG1grEU7LFwATxBPcmwAYw45BmBaTMEU-2gOAFtcnC5YcX5I9M54gBkNLR0wtpxDCAATZgB5ADdWNRJyS2tK6giFqKGijnZkvrbo5thVsA5YLwqt9J34vbXYHxP-qK5d_cOAZlu70QeLp9gAFjf3858S4HWAAVn-d0BvGBhwAbBD-lCYbAAOwI7afIHfAAc6LOmOh3wAnHi7Ejvl4AAykvTkq5eY6tAEE5G-Gn6FkU15MyGc-l_ZZYAC6C1CVCFPOwmTifF6tLA2Xq2HGHAIVghSzCBlYEGYCVgmz0aW21Tq7G19D1R3ZogVOXN6g4bB5tKeG0FIl8PlBPxdbWeoNhfvSXmxlODdhR4Y91C8Eb0QZjVB88eUYdTnthlOecaTWFD0dOdi8Px-PmeGeosOeZcrVCJsJTecwXiJ2MTRb0fk7wtFEeNZ1NSt4OqtN0rWXteUdzpj2DdSWbRx83t9S4DHfeLfTS8LW6Odawe63TZ7ImP7y8WZzh-3F7uJbLFaX1drS4bp_39_63f6IqLYq9mgARAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to show tooltip on hover of label just on top of that label. This tooltip is over the chart.

Comment: Yes, there isn't any way to do that. That's why I have suggested a different solution which is useful.